# Jetty: hot deploy of new files

Tags: deployment, jetty

Jetty's hot deployment is great. I use it every day via jetty:run and saves my day.

But.

It won't deploy new files (JSPs in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp) I create in my webapp.
It will just redeploy modified files.

Does anyone know a way to make Jetty hot deploy new files without restarting it?

This is my current configuration:

```
<configuration>
    <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
    <webAppSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</webAppSourceDirectory>
    <webAppConfig>
        <defaultsDescriptor>${basedir}/src/main/config/webdefault.xml</defaultsDescriptor>
        <contextPath>/${project.artifactId}</contextPath>
        <jettyEnvXml>${project.build.directory}/jetty/jetty-env.xml</jettyEnvXml>
    </webAppConfig>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding scanTarget parameter to your config above.

```
<scanTargets>
    <scanTarget>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp</scanTarget>
</scanTargets>
```

Answer (score 0):

With a "normal" configuration of jsps, there is no need for jetty to hot redeploy the context when a jsp is added/changed. The Jasper jsp container makes the new/modified jsp available when you hit its url *without restarting the context*.

However, in your case, you have put your jsps inside WEB-INF, which is a location that is forbidden to be served. You must have put in some kind of server-side redirect in order for jsps to be working at all. You didn't post your configuration, so I'm not sure what your redirect solution is.

I can tell you that the jetty-maven-plugin scans *only* for changes to particular files within WEB-INF (here's a link to an old document page that is still fairly accurate: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Which+files+are+scanned+by+the+Jetty+Maven+Plugin). So, if your redirect setup requires the context to be redeployed when new jsps are dropped into WEB-INF, then the answer given by Ayub Malik previously re using the extra scanTargets is a valid one.

regards
Jan